# Matlab: Error using sin (squared)

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

```
theta = (0:0.01:2*pi)

r = sin.^2.*(theta) + cos.^2.*(theta)
```

it returns me this error;

> Error using sin. Not enough input arguments.

I am confused, what do i need to change?

Comment: Do you realise that `sin(x).^2 + cos(x).^2 = 1` is a trigonometric identity, so `r` will always be 1?

Comment: Haha yes it is, but it's not undefined, theta is a variable for the vector shown above, so it would not equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sine squared can be done with either:

```
sin(x).*sin(x)
```

or

```
sin(x).^2
```

Answer (score 1):

`r = (sin(theta)).^2 + (cos(theta)).^2`